# How to programmatically upload a specific file via WebView without FileChooser

Tags: java, android, file-upload, webview

I am developing an application that connects to a router's web interface via WebView and automatically do some configurations...
An important step of the configuration, is to upgrade the router's firmware (which .bin file will be already stored in my Android device). I would like to make all this, without any user interaction.
How could I trigger the `<input type="file">` inside the WebView, and automatically select the specific file and upload it? (without even showing a Select File Dialog)

I have the following overriding method, inside my WebChromeClient:

```
final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;

    @Override
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        Log.d("DEV_onShowFileChooser", "executed!");

        Uri uri[] = new Uri[]{Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/firmware.bin")};

        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(uri);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

        return true;
    }
}
```

When I manually click in the `<input type="file">` inside the WebView, I can see that Log.d in the Logcat, but nothing happens, the file is not being uploaded to the input. What am I missing here?

Comment: `How to programmatically upload a specific file to WebView` To your WebView? To your router i think.

Comment: @blackapps thanks, I've corrected it

Comment: Just show how you would do it using the file chooser. After that you modify that code.